# Attribute missing in socket module(s)

Tags: python, sockets

I work on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I need to use `getpeername` for a script I'm working on. I get the `AttributeError` because it's not there: `dir(socket)` gives everything but `getpeername`. However, 'GETPEERNAME 1' is in all pyconfig.h files listed. This is true for 2.7, 3.4 and held when I did a fresh OS install on another computer (just to see if it was a question of superimposed installs). Is it a 14.04 issue? Is it fixable? I'm lost.

```
import socket

n= 1024
M= 65535
L=[]

while n<= int(M):
        target = "0.0.0.0"
        port = n
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
                server.bind ((target, port))
                print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (target, port)
        except:
                print (port,'Busy')
                L.append (port)

        n=n+1
print (L)
socket.getpeername(L[2])
```

Comment: Provide you code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getpeername()` is not a part of `socket` module, it is a part of socket object. Also it is useless for listening sockets because they do not have peers.

You're probably need something like this:

```
clnt_sock, _ = server.accept()
print clnt_sock.getpeername()
```

Also, your listening path is incorrect, you forgot to call `listen`:

```
server.listen(5)
```